# django UserCreationForm doesn't save

Tags: python, django

gentlemans i've got a problem with the user registration, data is not saved to model Profile, everything is saved only in Users, i think that signals's work incorrect

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, 'Your account has been created')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(instance, sender, **kwargs, created):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: What do you want to save and is not saving?

Comment: Image is a mandatory field from what i can see.

Comment: even with (ImageField(upload_to=... blank=True, null=True) it's stil doesn't work

Comment: Yeas i want to save that data from register form to Profiles

Answer (score 0):

i found a problem, just should should add in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS instead a line 'users' i should add 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]
```